# What do stack build plan exceptions mean?

Tags: cabal, haskell-stack

I have a project that needs some action in order to compile. For some dependencies, the error message states two versions and one range. What do these entries actually mean?

```
    Cabal-1.24.2.0 must match ==2.0.* (latest applicable is 2.0.0.2)
```

Under no circumstances I would expect `Cabal-1.24.2.0` to match version in `2.0.*` range. The `stack` too seems to demand so without explaining why.

Why is `2.0.0.2` considered applicable given LTS version is `1.24.2.0`? Does this mean it is compatible?

Comment: I've added https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3438 about how the messaging might be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's saying that the LTS version, Cabal-1.24.2.0, does not match the ==2.0.* constraint that comes from some package, probably in the project you are trying to build.

"latest applicable" is the most recent version on hackage that fits within the constraint range.  You can try adding it to your `extra-deps`.

Perhaps this messaging should be improved, but then again that will make it less easily searchable.